# How to copy from object with out using the table index

Tags: json, jq, edit

The input is

```
{
"zoo": [
   { "x": { "guesst": "" } },
   { "y": { "guesst": "zebra" } }
  ]
}
```

And i need the output like

```
{
"zoo": [
   { "x": { "guesst": "zebra" } },
   { "y": { "guesst": "zebra" } }
  ]
}
```

I did:

```
jq '.zoo[0].x.guesst = .zoo[1].y.guesst'
```

But, what if i do not know the order of the objects in the array?

Comment: So you want to copy y.guesst to x.guesst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over all items using [`.[]`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#array-object-value-iterator), and use [`select`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#select) and [`has`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#has) to filter for the right ones:

```bash
jq '(.zoo[] | select(has("x"))).x.guesst = (.zoo[] | select(has("y"))).y.guesst'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WxWQA7iFCfR)