# How to copy field from nested object inside array

Tags: json, jq, edit

My json input is:

```
{
"zoo": [
   { "room": { "name": "x" }, "gpu": { "id": "fish",  "sum": 0 } },
   { "room": { "name": "y" }, "gpu": { "id": "zebra", "sum": 797 } }
  ]
}
```

I need to copy from zebra's sum into fish's sum. So, the output will be looked like:

```
{
"zoo": [
   { "room": { "name": "x" }, "gpu": { "id": "fish",  "sum": 797 } },
   { "room": { "name": "y" }, "gpu": { "id": "zebra", "sum": 797 } }
  ]
}
```

But, I could not know the order of the table, so, I could not use the tables index.  Actually, I need to do it be the field "name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78035792/2158479), iterate over all items using [`.[]`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#array-object-value-iterator), and use [`select`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#select) to filter for the right ones:

```bash
(.zoo[].gpu | select(.id == "fish").sum) =
(.zoo[].gpu | select(.id == "zebra").sum)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KsfNh1wXpJ6)

> Actually, I need to do it be the field "name".

```bash
(.zoo[] | select(.room.name == "x").gpu.sum) =
(.zoo[] | select(.room.name == "y").gpu.sum)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2kkIfIklxqW)

Comment: The jq is not easy to learn.  You help me so much. Thanks pmf.

Answer (score 0):

A pedestrian but fairly robust solution would be:

```
(.zoo|first(.[]|select(.room.name=="y").gpu.sum)//null) as $sum
| if $sum
  then .zoo |= map(if .room.name=="x" then .gpu.sum=$sum else . end)
  else .
  end
```